# compose a list of Int from a list of Other Thing in scala

Tags: scala, list, int, reduce, fold

I'm new in SCALA and  I want to compose a list of Int from another List call services. this List of Object Service contains a Int field name codeService, and I want to get a List of all codeService from my services list..
I do something like that:

```scala
def listaIndicesServicios(servicios: List[Servicio], indices: List[Int]): List[Int]={
if(servicios.length==0){
indices
}
else {
val listaNueva = servicios.head.codigoServicio :: indices
  listaIndicesServicios(servicios.tail, listaNueva)
}
}
```

and the  call my method:

```
val lista = listaIndicesServicios(servicios.servicios.reverse,List())
```

But I think that my brain is too imperative yet. and I think that with foldRigth or reduce or something like that I could get a better functional approuch... can you help me thanks

Comment: `servicios.map(_.codigoServicio)`

Comment: FYI both [`foldRight`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#foldRight[B](z:B)(op:(A,B)=>B):B) and [`reduce`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#reduce[A1>:A](op:(A1,A1)=>A1):A1) tranform a collection into a single item (which can be a collection I suppose). You are trying to transform each element in a collection to a new item in a new collection so you will want [`map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#reduce[A1>:A](op:(A1,A1)=>A1):A1), as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.map` method to transform your List[Service] in a List[Int]. Something like:

```
servicios.map(servicio => servicio.codigoServicio)
```

or, scala allows you to write:

```
servicios.map(_.codigoServicio)
```